# How to get non-frozen rows?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Is there some attribute that returns free rows or an empty array []?
In the query, I freeze the columns with lock: true and I would like all subsequent queries to work exclusively on unlocked rows.

```
const t = sequelize.transaction();
const res = await sleep(async () => {
 const result = await Product.findAll({limit: 2, lock: true}, {transaction: t});
return result;
}, timer);
```

Example:
Here I get `[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]`
/test?timer=10000

Here I expect to get `[{ id: 3 }, { id: 4 }]`, but it still outputs `[{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]`
/test?timer=0

Comment: I decided to just add the isFreezed column, which will immediately change the status to true when received. All subsequent requests will wait until the first one is completed. Yes, it's sad, but I won't have many visitors, so I don't think anything bad will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL Version: 8.0.30 (Required version from 8.0.1)
MySQL Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-using-skip-locked-and-nowait-to-handle-hot-rows/
Sequelize: 6.30.0

Documentation: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/transactions/#locks

You need to add the `skipLocked: true` parameter, but that didn't work for me. Perhaps in the current version of sequelize for dialect mysql this option does not work.

The solution to this problem is the following code:

```
const result = await sequelize.query(`${sqlQuery} FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;`, { transaction })
```